# Multiple aerospike nodes on docker

Tags: docker, aerospike

I want to have multiple instances of an aerospike-server node so load balance because I hit the server with so many requests I get an error saying 'Error Code 22: Operation not allow at this time'.

I assume that having more aerospike-server nodes that i can lessen the load on one node and therefore complete more operations? I'm jsut not sure where to start with this.

I need these nodes all locally on one host. Any help would be great.

My network knowledge isn't great so forgive me for any

My DockerFile:

```
FROM aerospike/aerospike-server

MAINTAINER "xxxx"

ADD aerospike.conf /etc/aerospike/
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3"

services:
   aerospike-server:
      image: amc
      container_name: aerospike-server
      ports:
      - "3000:3000"
      - "3001:3001"
      - "3002:3002"
      - "3003:3003"
   aerospike-amc:
      image: mrbar42/aerospike-amc
      container_name: aerospike-amc
      ports:
      - "8081:8081"
```

aerospike.conf network stanza

```
network {
    service {
        address any
        port 3000

        # Uncomment the following to set the `access-address` parameter to the
        # IP address of the Docker host. This will the allow the server to correctly
        # publish the address which applications and other nodes in the cluster to
        # use when addressing this node.
        # access-address <IPADDR>
    }

    heartbeat {

        # mesh is used for environments that do not support multicast
        mode mesh
        port 3002

        # use asinfo -v 'tip:host=<ADDR>;port=3002' to inform cluster of
        # other mesh nodes
        interval 150
        timeout 10
    }

    fabric {
        # address any
        port 3001
    }

    info {
        # address any
        port 3003
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you post the complete error code 22 error. Seems you may be running too many scans and may also need to tune your scans settings https://discuss.aerospike.com/t/aerospike-getmany-failed-error-22/2489/10 Increasing, it would be interesting to see if you have reached any proto-fd-max limits http://www.aerospike.com/docs/reference/configuration#proto-fd-max. You can definitely try more docker instances by configuring them on different ports on the same node.

Comment: Unfortunately that's the full error i get. Yes i'm doing many scans. That's what i'm trying to achieve, running more nodes, but not quite sure how.

Comment: you could try increasing scan-max-active and scan threads first: http://www.aerospike.com/docs/operations/manage/scans#manage  Are you using an overlay network or docker host network? running another instance may depend on they type of config you have. Can u post your docker run and dockerfile along with your question.

Comment: I've increase the scan-maxactive & done to 200(seems to be the limit) and scan-threads to 8, don't get any more errors but the process seems to take longer. I'm using a docker host network. I've updated my question.

Comment: Since you are on the same host, you could configure your instances to use multicast network: http://www.aerospike.com/docs/operations/configure/network/heartbeat#multicast-heartbeat and configure each one of the docker instances to use different ports. (ie: for a 3 node cluster, 3 separate aerospike.conf with : 3000-3003, 4000-4003, and 5000-5003) Please see: https://discuss.aerospike.com/t/aerospike-docker-container-3-6-3-is-not-forming-a-cluster/3193/3

Comment: Ok i've got 2 docker instances of an aerospike-server with multicast enabled. But on AMC can't detect the other node. Also in logs it still says cluster size 1..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143052/discussion-between-snazzywolf-and-lvolmar).

Comment: We can continue the troubleshooting and benefit the community on https://discuss.aerospike.com/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use a multicast heartbeat configuration and get a small cluster of aerospike nodes running on a single machine.

Here are the steps I used:

1) Get the latest Dockerfile from the aerospike repo

git clone https://github.com/aerospike/aerospike-server.docker.git

2) Modify the heartbeat section and use multicast:

```
    heartbeat {

            mode multicast
            multicast-group 239.1.99.2
            port 9918

            interval 150
            timeout 10
    }
```

3) Build image and cluster with either docker-compose or custom script.

I used the following custom makecluster.sh bash shell script:

```
cat makecluster.sh 
docker build -t "aerospike/aerospike-server" .
for i in {3..9} ; do
echo $i;
docker stop aerospike${i}
docker rm aerospike${i}
docker run -tid --name aerospike${i} -p ${i}000:3000 -p ${i}001:3001 -p ${i}002:3002 -p ${i}003:3003 aerospike/aerospike-server
done;
```

and run:

```
 ./makecluster.sh 
Sending build context to Docker daemon  12.8 kB
Step 1/10 : FROM ubuntu:xenial
 ---> 2fa927b5cdd3
Step 2/10 : ENV AEROSPIKE_VERSION 3.12.1
 ---> Using cache
 ---> f9740fe0e5b5
Step 3/10 : ENV AEROSPIKE_SHA256 16ceb0d131892c3caab31ee031f7e37d7a611c22686fec2692facde87ac69a00
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 5e7fbc820f7a
Step 4/10 : RUN apt-get update -y   && apt-get install -y wget python python-argparse python-bcrypt python-openssl logrotate net-tools iproute2 iputils-ping   && wget "https://www.aerospike.com/artifacts/aerospike-server-community/${AEROSPIKE_VERSION}/aerospike-server-community-${AEROSPIKE_VERSION}-ubuntu16.04.tgz" -O aerospike-server.tgz   && echo "$AEROSPIKE_SHA256 *aerospike-server.tgz" | sha256sum -c -   && mkdir aerospike   && tar xzf aerospike-server.tgz --strip-components=1 -C aerospike   && dpkg -i aerospike/aerospike-server-*.deb   && dpkg -i aerospike/aerospike-tools-*.deb   && mkdir -p /var/log/aerospike/   && mkdir -p /var/run/aerospike/   && rm -rf aerospike-server.tgz aerospike /var/lib/apt/lists/*   && dpkg -r wget ca-certificates   && dpkg --purge wget ca-certificates   && apt-get purge -y
 ---> Using cache
 ---> a1d797e088fa
Step 5/10 : COPY aerospike.conf /etc/aerospike/aerospike.conf
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 7bb9f5326c7b
Step 6/10 : COPY entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 345534f6c3b8
Step 7/10 : VOLUME /opt/aerospike/data
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 3f07a5e4b113
Step 8/10 : EXPOSE 3000 3001 3002 3003
 ---> Using cache
 ---> e081dff6a725
Step 9/10 : ENTRYPOINT /entrypoint.sh
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 923ff0299e70
Step 10/10 : CMD asd
 ---> Using cache
 ---> a05c71468897
Successfully built a05c71468897
3
aerospike3
aerospike3
4d2df0569581c967d29750a5f7f6e67fc1835e1f6b78157eb5c8b11f843a222b
4
aerospike4
aerospike4
3173f06d9012996ce318855d982fbc20c5985beb7e356863a0075ce3ae337b21
5
aerospike5
aerospike5
10592f8ca508c678cd67695402f3c23ad417716772cf5a20de91c3e178bb1c28
6
aerospike6
aerospike6
7ddac9e31db5b618114c155b40d8ad524b629e96c514837a36854cf420a29d5c
7
aerospike7
aerospike7
6168421deffead460ac238b2a9817769e29d3c68eca33863cf9b0e19a8c09a0f
8
aerospike8
aerospike8
9d1761592c30b1460c064ef06f70067217e1b1c61f3efc2b016113b4869cfc6f
9
aerospike9
aerospike9
67c37f2f6ebae065eef978dcf4683b6ad5bd18bed0411e3d6681c723776c1834
```

5) Verify cluster info :

Use docker exec to run asadm tool

```
docker exec -ti aerospike7 asadm
Aerospike Interactive Shell, version 0.1.9

Found 7 nodes
Online:  172.17.0.2:3000, 172.17.0.8:3000, 172.17.0.3:3000, 172.17.0.4:3000, 172.17.0.7:3000, 172.17.0.6:3000, 172.17.0.5:3000

Admin> 


Admin> info
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~Network Information~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
             Node               Node                Ip      Build   Cluster            Cluster     Cluster         Principal   Rackaware   Client     Uptime   
                .                 Id                 .          .      Size                Key   Integrity                 .        Mode    Conns          .   
172.17.0.2:3000     BB9020011AC4202    172.17.0.2:3000   C-3.12.1         7   8DBD43898C508D41   True        BB9080011AC4202   none             7   00:06:03   
172.17.0.3:3000     BB9030011AC4202    172.17.0.3:3000   C-3.12.1         7   8DBD43898C508D41   True        BB9080011AC4202   none             8   00:06:02   
172.17.0.4:3000     BB9040011AC4202    172.17.0.4:3000   C-3.12.1         7   8DBD43898C508D41   True        BB9080011AC4202   none             8   00:06:00   
172.17.0.5:3000     BB9050011AC4202    172.17.0.5:3000   C-3.12.1         7   8DBD43898C508D41   True        BB9080011AC4202   none             6   00:05:58   
172.17.0.7:3000     BB9070011AC4202    172.17.0.7:3000   C-3.12.1         7   8DBD43898C508D41   True        BB9080011AC4202   none            10   00:05:55   
172.17.0.8:3000     *BB9080011AC4202   172.17.0.8:3000   C-3.12.1         7   8DBD43898C508D41   True        BB9080011AC4202   none             6   00:05:52   
6168421deffe:3000   BB9060011AC4202    172.17.0.6:3000   C-3.12.1         7   8DBD43898C508D41   True        BB9080011AC4202   none             8   00:05:56   
Number of rows: 7

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~Namespace Information~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Namespace                Node   Avail%   Evictions                 Master                Replica     Repl     Stop             Pending       Disk    Disk     HWM        Mem     Mem    HWM      Stop   
        .                   .        .           .   (Objects,Tombstones)   (Objects,Tombstones)   Factor   Writes            Migrates       Used   Used%   Disk%       Used   Used%   Mem%   Writes%   
        .                   .        .           .                      .                      .        .        .             (tx,rx)          .       .       .          .       .      .         .   
test        172.17.0.2:3000     99         0.000     (0.000  ,0.000  )      (0.000  ,0.000  )      2        false    (0.000  ,0.000  )   0.000 B    0       50      0.000 B    0       60     90        
test        172.17.0.3:3000     99         0.000     (0.000  ,0.000  )      (0.000  ,0.000  )      2        false    (0.000  ,0.000  )   0.000 B    0       50      0.000 B    0       60     90        
test        172.17.0.4:3000     99         0.000     (0.000  ,0.000  )      (0.000  ,0.000  )      2        false    (0.000  ,0.000  )   0.000 B    0       50      0.000 B    0       60     90        
test        172.17.0.5:3000     99         0.000     (0.000  ,0.000  )      (0.000  ,0.000  )      2        false    (0.000  ,0.000  )   0.000 B    0       50      0.000 B    0       60     90        
test        172.17.0.7:3000     99         0.000     (0.000  ,0.000  )      (0.000  ,0.000  )      2        false    (0.000  ,0.000  )   0.000 B    0       50      0.000 B    0       60     90        
test        172.17.0.8:3000     99         0.000     (0.000  ,0.000  )      (0.000  ,0.000  )      2        false    (0.000  ,0.000  )   0.000 B    0       50      0.000 B    0       60     90        
test        6168421deffe:3000   99         0.000     (0.000  ,0.000  )      (0.000  ,0.000  )      2        false    (0.000  ,0.000  )   0.000 B    0       50      0.000 B    0       60     90        
test                                       0.000     (0.000  ,0.000  )      (0.000  ,0.000  )                        (0.000  ,0.000  )   0.000 B                    0.000 B                             
Number of rows: 8
```

Note: Tools like AMC or asadm , may not be able to see the full cluster if running outside of a docker container on the host machine. In such use case, you may need to try a docker host network and different listening ports in aerospike.conf  or the alternative is to run AMC in a container.

6) If using --network=host then you will need to modify the listening ports in aerospike.conf. Each instance running on the same host with same ip address should use a different port when using host network.

Example:

```
cat makecluster.sh 
docker build -t "aerospike/aerospike-server" .
for i in {6..9} ; do
echo $i;
docker stop aerospike${i}
docker rm aerospike${i}
docker run -tid --name aerospike${i} -v /root/docker/aerospike-server.docker/aerospike${i}:/etc/aerospike --network host -p ${i}000:${i}000 -p ${i}001:${i}001 -p ${i}002:${i}002 -p ${i}003:${i}003 aerospike/aerospike-server
done;
```

Sample config directory and file:

```
cat aerospike7/aerospike.conf 
# Aerospike database configuration file.

# This stanza must come first.
service {
    user root
    group root
    paxos-single-replica-limit 1 # Number of nodes where the replica count is automatically reduced to 1.
    pidfile /var/run/aerospike/asd.pid
    service-threads 4
    transaction-queues 4
    transaction-threads-per-queue 4
    proto-fd-max 15000
}

logging {

    # Log file must be an absolute path.
    file /var/log/aerospike/aerospike.log {
        context any info
    }

    # Send log messages to stdout
    console {
        context any info 
    }
}

network {
    service {
        # Add interface name for network card used by host
        address br0 
        # Modify port to be used by your aerospike container
        port 7000

        # Uncomment the following to set the `access-address` parameter to the
        # IP address of the Docker host. This will the allow the server to correctly
        # publish the address which applications and other nodes in the cluster to
        # use when addressing this node.
        # access-address <IPADDR>
    }

    heartbeat {


            mode multicast
            multicast-group 239.1.99.2
            port 9918


        interval 150
        timeout 10
    }

    fabric {
        # Modify port to be used by your aerospike container
        port 7001
    }

    info {
        # Modify port to be used by your aerospike container
        port 7003
    }
}

namespace test {
    replication-factor 2
    memory-size 1G
    default-ttl 5d # 5 days, use 0 to never expire/evict.

    #   storage-engine memory

    # To use file storage backing, comment out the line above and use the
    # following lines instead.
    storage-engine device {
        file /opt/aerospike/data/test.dat
        filesize 4G
        data-in-memory true # Store data in memory in addition to file.
    }
}
```

asadm output:

```
asadm -p 7000
Aerospike Interactive Shell, version 0.1.9

Found 4 nodes
Online:  192.168.100.148:9000, 192.168.100.148:7000, 192.168.100.148:8000, 192.168.100.148:6000

Admin> info
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~Network Information~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                     Node                Node                     Ip      Build   Cluster            Cluster     Cluster          Principal   Rackaware   Client     Uptime   
                        .                  Id                      .          .      Size                Key   Integrity                  .        Mode    Conns          .   
node.local:6000   177160DE04CA0568    192.168.120.148:6000   C-3.12.1         4   5009B1D835FA3C06   True        232960DE04CA0568   none             3   00:28:37   
node.local:7000   1B5960DE04CA0568    192.168.120.148:7000   C-3.12.1         4   5009B1D835FA3C06   True        232960DE04CA0568   none             3   00:28:34   
node.local:8000   1F4160DE04CA0568    192.168.120.148:8000   C-3.12.1         4   5009B1D835FA3C06   True        232960DE04CA0568   none             3   00:28:30   
node.local:9000   *232960DE04CA0568   192.168.120.148:9000   C-3.12.1         4   5009B1D835FA3C06   True        232960DE04CA0568   none             4   00:28:25   
Number of rows: 4

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~Namespace Information~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Namespace                        Node   Avail%   Evictions                 Master                Replica     Repl     Stop             Pending       Disk    Disk     HWM        Mem     Mem    HWM      Stop   
        .                           .        .           .   (Objects,Tombstones)   (Objects,Tombstones)   Factor   Writes            Migrates       Used   Used%   Disk%       Used   Used%   Mem%   Writes%   
        .                           .        .           .                      .                      .        .        .             (tx,rx)          .       .       .          .       .      .         .   
test        node.local:6000   99         0.000     (0.000  ,0.000  )      (0.000  ,0.000  )      2        false    (0.000  ,0.000  )   0.000 B    0       50      0.000 B    0       60     90        
test        node.local:7000   99         0.000     (0.000  ,0.000  )      (0.000  ,0.000  )      2        false    (0.000  ,0.000  )   0.000 B    0       50      0.000 B    0       60     90        
test        node.local:8000   99         0.000     (0.000  ,0.000  )      (0.000  ,0.000  )      2        false    (0.000  ,0.000  )   0.000 B    0       50      0.000 B    0       60     90        
test        node.local:9000   99         0.000     (0.000  ,0.000  )      (0.000  ,0.000  )      2        false    (0.000  ,0.000  )   0.000 B    0       50      0.000 B    0       60     90        
test                                               0.000     (0.000  ,0.000  )      (0.000  ,0.000  )                        (0.000  ,0.000  )   0.000 B                    0.000 B
```

Comment: Great, thanks for this. I can see the cluster size being 7 in the logs now. I just need to see this cluster on AMC. I've built an amc container but it can't seem to detect the nodes.

Comment: Ok i've got them working by simply adding to my compose file but i can't seem to have more than 7 nodes up at the same time?